# Getting a count of each distinct row in SQL Server 

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How do I get this statement (which returns duplicates):

```
  Select Name from Table
```

To return this:

```
  Select Distinct Name, Count(Number of non-distinct Name rows)
```

?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS DistinctCount
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: I always tend to add ORDER BY 2 DESC to that type of query to get the largest number of duplicates at the top of the result set.

Comment: I know. I wasn't meaning it as contradiction to your answer. I just upvoted your answer and thought I'd add that as an added suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

select 
 Name,
 count(Name)
 from tableName
 GROUP BY name